# Dart - map from another class is aways null

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a screen, which will show the user, new notifications that he receives, from Firebase Cloud Messaging. When the onMessage method receives the notification, it arrives in a json format, which I inserted into a Map <dynamic, dynamic> variable. The problem is when I call this Map in another Stateful class, because the map is always null.

This is the class that assembles the view:

```
class PushList extends StatefulWidget {
  PushConfig config;

  String title, body;
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> push;

  PushList({this.push}) {}

  @override
  _PushListState createState() => _PushListState();
}

class _PushListState extends State<PushList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: widget._colors.white,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          widget.push == null
              ? Card(
                  elevation: 4,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text(
                    "Você não possui novas notificações.",
                  ),
                )
              : Card(
                  elevation: 4,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      widget.push['notification']['title'],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      widget.push['notification']['body'],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class that receives the notification and places it on the Map:

```
class PushConfig {
  Future<dynamic> pushAPIConfigMethod() async {
    fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<dynamic, dynamic> message) async {
        PushList(push: message);     // -> Here I try to send the map to the PushList class, using a parameter 
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final title = await message['notification']['title'];
        final body = await message['notification']['body'];
        print("title: $title | body: $body");
        return message;
      },
      onLaunch: (message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Before we can even start to help you, I can tell you that your code has issues. Your `PushList` StatefulWidget class has 3 variables declared, but only 1 in it's constructor, with an added pair of brackets after it. There's definitely something wrong there.

You are also accessing some StatelessWidget widget variables that aren't even there, and with an underscore behind them, declaring them as private. `widget._colors.white` That can't be right either.

Comment: Hello John, those two variables not used in the constructor were from other tests that I have been doing in this class. As for the widget._colors.white, it was also for color tests that I did in this class. I removed the class that showed these colors, and forgot to remove the code above, I'm sorry for that.